# Flask Jinja2 template not keeping text indented when returned to template?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a simple flask an html template that opens a text file and returns the content on the web page as shown below. It also highlights certain text with the "mark" tag. It works great except that the text is is not keeping the indentation as it is in the source file.

The source looks like this with some lines indented;

```
interface Ethernet3/3
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
```

but the code I have for the Jinja2 template will return it like this with everything flush to the left and not keeping the indents ;

```
interface Ethernet3/3
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
ip address 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
```

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as f:
   textfile = [line.strip() for line in f]
  return render_template('my-form.html', textfile=textfile)


The HTML template has this;

{% for line in textfile %}
 {% if 'interface' in line %}
 <p><mark>{{ line }}</mark></p>
 {% else %}
 <p> {{ line }} </p>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I have the indents maintained when sending the text to the template?

Comment: `line.strip()` removes leading whitespaces. Just skip the `strip()` call and it should work as expected. Also, you can add a `print(textfile)` statement before rendering to check whether the correct result is being passed to `render_template()` and track where things got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As @Freguglia states, `line.strip` removes leading whitespace.

It might be better to simply load your file with:

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as f:
    textfile = f.read()
```

Also, most browsers won't display multiple spaces, unless you wrap that text in `<pre>` tags.  If your source file was to have further levels of indentation, then you'd want the template code to be:

```
<pre>{{textfile}}</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this was the issue. I had to use readlines() though like this: with open("testfile2.txt", "r") as f:
   textfile = f.readlines()